# React JS - Display state from link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to display state from link, like this :

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/courses/product/productlist', state: { fromDashboard: true }}}> Food & Treats </Link>
```

How can I display state in component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State will be available in `location` props inside component.

Access the state like this:

```
render(){
   console.log('state', this.props.location.state.fromDashboard);
   return (....)
}
```

Check the **[Doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)** for more details.